# Moving a vertex on a curve rotates the whole curve

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am trying to model hair, but when i try to move a vertex from the curve, everything rotates

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the image, the only transformation done was a location on the X axis (although it happens with all axes). But everything rotates/titls instead.

Twist method is set to Minimum, as Tangent just flattens everything and Z-up presents the same problem but insted of everything, only a few vertices rotate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling with a lot of settings i think I found a solution.

The thing for me is the handles were pointing downwards (you can see it by selecting the curve and checking the `Handles`box on the Overlays menu). Then with the curve selected, right click and choose Switch Direction, and then Ctrl+T 180 to tilt everything back to normal.

I don't exactly know what Switch Direction actually does or why it worked, but handles move fine now, so I'll consider it a temporary solution ig. I'll wait if someone has a definitive solution. But in the meantime, I hope this helps people with this problem.